# Convert JSON to a .NET dataset

Tags: .net, json

I am writing a Java servlet that uses the http://json.org/java/ libraries to read some data from a mssql database and convert the result set to a JSON string. This JSON string is being consumed by a .NET client app. The .net App calls the JavaServlet using HttpWebRequest object. This way I have a json string now in my .net app.

What I would like to do is convert this JSON string to a dataset so that I can display it it in a datagrid. All the examples that I have found online talk about converting a 'dataset to json'.. any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Json.NET library makes working with JavaScript and JSON formatted data in .NET simple. Quickly read and write JSON using the JsonReader and JsonWriter or serialize your .NET objects with a single method call using the JsonSerializer.

[Json.NET CodePlex Project](http://www.codeplex.com/json)

See [this](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) article

Answer (score 1):

I prefer kiwi.json  your can find a sample on datatable conversion right here: http://dancewithcode.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/case-study-custom-json-converter-for-datatable/

It will fit perfectly as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use RestSharp to interact with your service. I believe it has a converter to go to/from a dataset and JSON:
http://restsharp.org/